# IPN call coming through but Paypal server keeps resending them

Tags: paypal-ipn

My IPN scripts have been working for many years now and I have made no changes. Starting last week the PayPal server seems to think that I am not getting the messages. I have checked my server logs and all calls from paypal return 200 ok. The calls also do the database entries and mods as if everything is working, but PP server thinks I did not receive them, so they keep re sending. Any advice on how to diagnose would be greatly appreciated as you know how PP deals with these things.

IPN php scripts that have been working for years

they add entries into my database and return 200 ok from my server logs but paypal thinks I did not recieve them so they keep re-sending

Comment: There must be a specific way they would want the acknowledgement of the request. You must check the API documentation for the same.

Comment: I do that, and get all customer data to enter into my database. that all still works. thier server returns "VERIFIED" and all customer information about the purchase. Remember this has been working for years

Comment: Here is the [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/ipn/IPNIntro/#link-asampleipnmessageandresponse) it says and I quote "Important: After you have authenticated an IPN message (received a VERIFIED response from PayPal), you must perform these important checks before you can assume that the IPN is both legitimate and has not already been processed"

Answer (score 0):

Review your account's IPN history at: https://www.paypal.com/merchantnotification/ipn/history

This will show the HTTP status you are actually returning to PayPal. If PayPal is retrying the sending of IPNs, it is either receiving no response or an HTTP status other than 200.

Cross check with your web server's logs to confirm, and assuming you are sending something other than 200 proceed with debugging that issue.

Answer (score -1):

yes off course I checked IPN history. Most of them show no response code, My server logs show it responded 200 ok

Comment: You can add it as a comment rather than an answer.